# JFrame Always on top above Desktop but not Chrome etc

Tags: java, swing, jframe, always-on-top

So I have been looking for how I would make my java application stay "always on top". But only always on top of the Desktop. Since I don't wanna have it on top of my other apps. When I, for example, open Chrome etc it should be behind chrome but above the Desktop.

Comment: *Since I don't wanna have it on top of my other apps* All apps run on the desktop. Chrome is an app that runs on the desktop. Your Swing apps run on the desktop. There is no way to separate Java apps from other apps. So if you want your app to always be on top, then it will always be on top of Chrome as well.

Comment: If you create a Swing app with a JFrame, then you should create child windows as a JDialog and specify the frame as the parent of the dialog. Then the dialog will always be visible only if the frame is visible. So if you minimize the frame all the dialogs will be minimized as well. Maybe something like that is what you are looking for.